# Not able to download bob.ap package on Windows

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip

```
 Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
    Collecting bob.ap
      Using cached bob.ap-2.1.13.zip (88 kB)
      Installing build dependencies ... error
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error
    
    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I have tried to update pip and make a virtual environment to install the package.

Comment: Not sure why this has the `vs-code extensions` (extinctions?)  tag as this appears to be a pip package issue (also available through conda)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are installing the package on Windows.  The [install documentation for the bob package](https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/docs/bob/docs/stable/install.html) says:

> Bob does not work on Windows and hence no conda packages are available for it. It will not work even if you install it from source. If you are an experienced user and manage to make Bob work on Windows, please let us know through our mailing list.

It *should* be possible to [install the package in WSL or in a docker container running on WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-vscode), but the install directions don't mention that option at all, and I haven't tried it.

I also found [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50803149/17030540) about installing `bob` from source. which the install documentation links to.  It's a few years old still seems to be valid.  However, it won't get around the "Doesn't work in Windows" issue.